# find value in object based on multi level keys?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say I have an javascript object

```
i = {
   data1:{
     one:'555',
     two:'222'

   },
   data2:{
   }
}
```

I am suprised to see that there is no way to say i{data1}{one} to arrive at answer 555.. What is the most current way to get at this data without using a for loop?

Comment: `i.data1.one` is what you want? can you specify in detail?

Comment: Do you know the key names?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily arrive there with:

```
i.data1.one
```

or

```
i['data1']['one']
```